# Using another classes values from its getter method

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

I've spent a while trying different things to try to get this to homework assignment to work correctly but I can't figure it out and it's the very last part which I presume is staring me in the face. When I enter a first name and last name and press Add account and then confirm it should add an account to an arraylist and then when I press No. of Accounts It should show me how many accounts there are in total, however it keeps showing 0.

[image]

**BasicAccountList**

```
import java.util.*;


public class BasicAccountList
{
    private ArrayList < BasicAccount> accounts;

    /**
     * Create a BasicAccount. 
     */
    public BasicAccountList()
    {
        accounts = new ArrayList < BasicAccount>();
    }

    /**
     * Add an account to this account list.
     * @param account the accountobject to be added
     */
    public void addAccount(BasicAccount account)
    {
        accounts.add(account);
    }

    /**
     * Return the number of accounts currently held.
     * 
     * @return the number of accounts
     */
    public int getNumberOfAccounts()
    {
        return accounts.size();
    }

}
```

**BasicAccount**

```
public class BasicAccount
{
    private Name name;
    private String accountNumber;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Account.
     * The number of pointsHeld should should be set to
     * the supplied value.
     * 
     * @param fName The Account Holder's first name 
     * @param lName The Account Holder's last name
     * @param acctNumber The account number
     */
    public BasicAccount(String fName, String lName, String acctNumber)
    {

        name = new Name (fName, lName);
        accountNumber = acctNumber; 
    }

    // accessors

    /**
     * Get the Account Holder's first name
     * 
     * @return the Account Holder's first name
     */
    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return name.getFirst();
    }

    /**
     * Get the Account Holder's last name
     * 
     * @return the Account Holder's last name
     */
    public String getLastName()
    {
        return name.getLast();
    }

    /**
     * Get the Account Holder's account Number
     * 
     * @return the Account Holder's account number
     */
    public String getAccountNumber()
    {
        return accountNumber;
    }


    public void printAccountDetails()
    {
        System.out.println( toString());
    }     

    /**
     * Return details of an account as a formated string
     * 
     * @return the account details of a particular account
     */

    public String toString()    
    {
        String output = accountNumber + " ";
        output = output + name.toString() + "\n";      
        return output;
    }

    // mutators         
    /**
     * Change the first name
     * 
     * @param fName the new first name
     * 
     */
    public void setFirstName(String fName)
    {
        name.setFirst (fName);
    }

    /**
     * Change the last name
     * 
     * @param lName the new last name
     * 
     */
    public void setLastName(String lName)
    {
        name.setLast(lName);
    }


} // end Account class
```

**Relevant code in the GUI class**

```
/**
 * Write a description of class HW4GUI here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */

import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;

public class HW4GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener         
{
    private BasicAccountList accounts; 
    private JPanel buttonPanel; 
    private JButton jbtAdd;
    private JButton jbtNumber;
    private JButton jbtQuit;
    private JLabel jlbAcctNo;
    private  JLabel jlbFName;
    private JLabel jlbLName;
    private JTextField jtfAcctNo;
    private  JTextField jtfFName;
    private  JTextField jtfLName;
    private int nextAcctNo;
    private JPanel textPanel;

    public HW4GUI ()
    {
        makeFrame();
        showFrame();
        nextAcctNo = 1001;


    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
    {

        BasicAccountList accountlist = new BasicAccountList ();
        String item = ae.getActionCommand();
        String firstNameText = jtfFName.getText();
        String lastNameText = jtfLName.getText();
        String finalAccountNumber = jtfAcctNo.getText();

        if(item.equals("No. of Accounts"))
        {
            jbtAdd.setEnabled(false);
            jbtNumber.setText ("Clear");
            jlbAcctNo.setText("No. of accounts:");


            //accounts.getNumberOfAccounts();

            BasicAccount newaccount = new BasicAccount(firstNameText, lastNameText, finalAccountNumber);

            String accountTotal = Integer.toString (accountlist.getNumberOfAccounts());

            jtfAcctNo.setText (accountTotal);


        }


    }
```

Comment: what ur issue is? do you get any error?

Comment: There is no error, just that there is a problem with my arraylist and class function calls that I can't find that instead of returning say, 4 when I add 4 accounts instead returns 0.

Comment: Where is Name class?

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/BhsE2Wn26WRn7WyJxzweVf

Comment: where are `makeFrame();
        showFrame();
        nextAcctNo = 1001;` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create another `BasicAccountList` inside the `actionPerformed` method. This means, every time you click a button, you generate a new `BasicAccountList` and perform all operations on this list, not the one held by `HW4GUI`.

Comment: I tried removing that and changing this line of code
String accountTotal = Integer.toString (accounts.getNumberOfAccounts());

but now run into this problem - http://i.imgur.com/izm6w12.png

Comment: accounts isn't initialized in the constructor (atleast i think so). initialize it and it should work.

Comment: I tried both of these in the constructor but both don't fix it, unless I've wrote them wrong?

accounts= new BasicAccountList ();   ......................
        BasicAccountList accounts = new BasicAccountList();

Comment: you need to change these two things: add `accounts = new BasicAccountList();` in the constructor and replace `accountlist.getNumberOfAccounts()` in `actionPerformed` with `accounts.getNumberOfAccounts()`. if this doesn't fix it: please mark the line where the exception is thrown

Comment: Now there is no exception thrown but the original problem of 0 accounts is still there, it feels to me like the accounts aren't actually being added when I'm pressing Add Account. Could it be a problem with this line?

 BasicAccount newaccount = new BasicAccount(firstNameText, lastNameText, finalAccountNumber);

Comment: right, thats another issue of your code, nothing happens when you press "add account". thought you had another listener for that, but apparently you dont

Comment: add an else statement to the if and inside this else block, create and add the new account

Comment: I have now fixed it the code was 
accounts.addAccount(new BasicAccount(firstNameText, lastNameText, finalAccountNumber));    Thanks for the help, and everyone else's answers too!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing `ActionListener` in the class implementing `JFrame`, it would be better if you do it in a separate class (possibly in an anonymous class, but any class is fine).

Now you can have two separate classes implementing `ActionListener` and thus two separate implementations of `actionPerformed`, one for each button.

Attach those `ActionListener`s to the respective buttons and you should be good to go.

Note: account list should be a member of the frame, so you can share it across both `ActionListener`s.

Good luck.